# HttpsUrlConnection devuelve como respuesta Bad Request

Tags: android-studio

En una aplicación en Android, tengo que conectarme a una web mediante autenticación  básica y https.

```
        HttpsURLconexion = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conexion.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        byte[] datosconexion=Base64.encode((this.nusuario + ":" + this.nclave).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String tiraconexion=datosconexion.toString();
        conexion.setRequestProperty("\"Authorization\"", "\"Basic \"" + tiraconexion);
        conexion.setRequestProperty("\"Accept\"", "\"application/json\"");
        conexion.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 segundos
        conexion.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 segundos
        conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexion.setDoOutput(true);
        conexion.setUseCaches(false);
        conexion.connect();
        respuesta = String.valueOf(conexion.getResponseCode());
        conexion.disconnect();
```

Siempre me devuelve el código 400 (Bad Request). 
¿Alguna idea?. 
Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Creo que te sobran comillas, los headers no deben llevarlas

Answer (score 0):

Usando esto me ha funcionado:

```
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(nusuario,nclave.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        HttpsURLConnection conexion = null;
        conexion = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conexion.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        conexion.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 segundos
        conexion.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 segundos
        conexion.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conexion.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
        conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        conexion.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexion.setUseCaches(false);
        conexion.connect();
```

Por si le sirve a alguien.
Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Deberias escribir tu peticion asi:

```
    conexion.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + tiraconexion);
    conexion.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Hola Igmer. Gracias por tu respuesta. Eso ya lo había probado, y me devuelve el código 401, UnAuthorized, pero los datos de conexión (usuario, constraseña) son correctos (los gestiono yo en la web). Sigo buscando alguna solución. Gracias de todas formas.